# Array to String Conversion Error In Codeigniter for multiple update

Tags: arrays, database, codeigniter, sql-update

morning,
 I would like to multiple update data to data base using explode expression

here my controller :

```
 $id                 = explode(' ',$this->post('id'));
 $respond            = $this->model->update($id,$data);
```

my model :

```
 public function update($id=null,$data=null)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
        return true;        
    }
```

Comment: Your ID get Multiple data?

Comment: $id variable is an array?

Comment: @DilipSolanki i hope you solf my problem again , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49727259/multiple-update-using-explode-where-in-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment86468200_49727259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your ID get multple data that time try this...

```
public function update($id=null,$data=null)
{
  for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id[$i]);
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
  }
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: I would like to add, that if it imperative that all the data makes it in or none at all - you should use/wrap this in a transaction.