# multiple update using explode & where in (codeigniter)

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, explode, where-in

Morning guys,

I would like to update multiple row using explode function and where in for code igniter, but the problem is, all rows all updated.

here is my controller :

```
$ids = explode(',', $this->post('id'));
$this->chatmod->update(array('id'=>$ids),$data);
```

my model :

```
public function update($ids=null,$data=null)
    {
        $this->db->where_in($ids);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: $ids is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating using column id you need to pass the column name in the `where_in` function like `$this->db->where_in("id",$idarray);`

For your code Try the below code:

```
public function update($ids=null,$data=null)
{
    $this->db->where_in('id',$ids);////Pass the column name of the database as first argument.
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `where_in` query should be supplied with target column, like :

```
$ids = explode(',', $this->post('id'));
$this->chatmod->update($ids,$data);

public function update($ids=null,$data=null)
    {
        $this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
        return true;
    }
```